# how to get id of the selected items of ListView where the data is coming from sever in Json format

Tags: android, listview, get, android-volley, key-value

```
my JSON:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "identity": 1,
            "email": "riya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 2,
            "email": "riya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 3,
            "email": "priyanka@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 4,
            "email": "priyanka@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 5,
            "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 6,
            "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 7,
            "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 8,
            "email": "priya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 9,
            "email": "priya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 10,
            "email": "priya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 11,
            "email": "priya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 12,
            "email": "priya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 13,
            "email": "priya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 14,
            "email": "jaya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 15,
            "email": "jaya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 16,
            "email": "priyanka@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 17,
            "email": "jaya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 18,
            "email": "kinjal@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 19,
            "email": "kinjal@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 20,
            "email": "kinjal@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 21,
            "email": "priyankapatell@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 22,
            "email": "priyankapatelle@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 23,
            "email": "priyankapatelre@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 24,
            "email": "priyankart@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 25,
            "email": "priyankarthjjk@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 26,
            "email": "priyajjk@o2h.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 27,
            "email": "riya@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 28,
            "email": "risha@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 29,
            "email": "rishad@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 30,
            "email": "rishaTiwari@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "identity": 31,
            "email": "textview"
        },
        {
            "identity": 32,
            "email": "textw"
        },
        {
            "identity": 33,
            "email": "tetw"
        },
        {
            "identity": 34,
            "email": "Textdddd"
        },
        {
            "identity": 35,
            "email": "tevvtw"
        },
        {
            "identity": 36,
            "email": "Textdhdjdk"
        },
        {
            "identity": 37,
            "email": "TextVlfggfg"
        },
        {
            "identity": 38,
            "email": "TextViewllkk"
        },
        {
            "identity": 39,
            "email": "TextViewghjm"
        },
        {
            "identity": 40,
            "email": "Te"
        },
        {
            "identity": 41,
            "email": "TextView133"
        },
        {
            "identity": 42,
            "email": "TextViewjkgjk"
        },
        {
            "identity": 43,
            "email": "TextViewIhhh"
        },
        {
            "identity": 47,
            "email": "TextViewhskslsld"
        },
        {
            "identity": 48,
            "email": "TextViewakskks"
        },
        {
            "identity": 49,
            "email": "TextVisjskdldk"
        },
        {
            "identity": 50,
            "email": "TedudidoxtView"
        },
        {
            "identity": 51,
            "email": "TextViewhddkdk"
        }
    ]
}
```

step-1: get value from JSON data map it key:value => identity:email.

step-2: show email in ListView.

step-3:select emails from ListView.

step-4:show selected emails on next activity.

step-5: get key of the selected emails.

Now please tell me how can I do that?
I am using volley library to get data I am able to show emails in the list view and also putting selected ListView on next activity but how can I get ids for emails for my post request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Serializable Class

```
public class DataClass implements Serializable {

    public int id;
    public String email;
}
```

create list of DataClass

```
List<DataClass> selectedList;
```

Put your data on selectedList

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position,long arg3) {
               //add validation email is already selected
               DataClass data = new DataClass();
               data.email = list.get(position).email;
               data.id = list.get(position).Id;
               selectedList.add(data);
            }
        });
```

On your intent

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("value", selectedList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

On Second Activity Get selected emails data and do Post Request

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        List<DataClass> datas=
               (List<DataClass>)bundle.getSerializable("value");
        doPostRequest(datas) // you can get your id's and email's on selected on list
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. override setOnitemClickListener of ListView
2. Then use 'Position' parameter to get id of selected item.

Comment: this will get the id's(position) of index of array ,but i want to get key as i showed in post so i can you that id for next post request.

Comment: Try this
try {
            JSONObject main = new JSONObject("MyJSON");
            JSONArray myData = main.getJSONArray("data");
          String email =  myData.get(position);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Get selected Item ID from listview,Try below like this,

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       // get you clicked item posion here
       Log.e("USERID",list.get(position).getId+"");
       Log.e("USEREMAIL",list.get(position).getEmail+"");
    }
});
```

I hope this may help you,All the best.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to map identity as emai's key in array which i am getting in json along with email, so that i can pass that identity  to the post request with selected items.

Answer (score -1):

Set this array list to list view and item selected of list view get email from list using list view position.

**Example :** email = list.get(i).getEmail();

```
 Arraylist<Pojo> list=new Arraylist();
    JsonArray jsonArray=new JsonArray("data");
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray;i++)
    {
       JsonObject jobject=jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
       String identity=jobject.getString("identity");
       String email=jobject.getString("email");
       Pojo pojo=new Pojo(identity,email);
       list.add(pojo)
    }
```